# Native query in jpa - getting entries due next week

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to retrieve all the entries that are due next week from the database. The query I wrote is:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT new model.dto.EntryDTO(v.name, e.e_number, e.dueDate, e.amount, eScan.scanTimestamp) FROM Entry e JOIN EntryScan eScan ON e.e_number = eScan.e_number JOIN Ve v ON e.vId= v.id WHERE e.dueDate BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE AND (CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '1 week')",
        nativeQuery = true)
    List<EntryDTO> findAllDueNextWeek();
```

and i get `JDBC exception executing SQL org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "." Position: 21`. `dueDate` is type date. I have similar query to this that works perfectly with the DTO class. I guess the problem is with the syntax and the `CURRENT_DATE` and `interval` part. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This constructer expression approach don't work when `nativeQuery=true`.

If you need to use native sql you can use [Interface-based Projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces) feature:

```java
public interface EntryView {
    Long getId();
    String getName();
}

@Query(value = "SELECT e.id, e.name FROM entry_table e", nativeQuery = true)
List<EntryView> findAllDueNextWeek();
```

`-OR-`

You can remove the `nativeQuery=true` statement and make your query conform to JPQL and use the constructer expression.

Comment: As I have updated the question, I have another very similar query to this one that works fine. I guess it's about the syntax of current_date or interval part?

Comment: Does it contain `nativeQuery=true` and constructer expression? Add your working sample code if you want.

Comment: Your proposed solutions from above worked. Thank you!